# Change default burning drive in ICDBurn windows api

Tags: c++, windows, api, cd

I'm currently using ICDBurn interface to burn cd succesfully in windows xp ([ICDBurn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776155(v=vs.85).aspx)). However, i'm not able to figure out how to change the default volume to burn. For example, my default volume is located in D:\, I want to use ICBurn to burn in E:\ . I would prefer not to use IMAPI, since ICDBurn is working fine.

Thanks :)

Comment: The API seems to not allow that.

Comment: Remarks for `GetRecorderDriveLetter()` state that *Only one drive on a system can have this option selected* in relation to which burnable drive it returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no supported way to change the default volume to burn. if you need to customize the burning process, you'll have to use something like IMAPI.